# Post To Twitter on Behalf of Another User using Node.js, express, twit, and passport-twitter

Tags: node.js, authentication, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

Using the Twitter API, I'm trying to post a tweet on behalf of a Twitter user.

I'm using node and the [passport-twitter](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter) and [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) modules.

Some resources:

- I followed this video tutorial [NodeJS and ExpressJS: Using Twitter
  authentication via Passport](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6QrV5pneSY).
- Sourcecode for the tutorial
  [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a6a65e5db0b623e02be6a534b73fde20).
- [Passport-twitter documentation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter)
- [twit documentation](https://github.com/ttezel/twit)

I *successfully* authenticated with passport-twitter following the tutorial above.

I also *successfully* posted using twit on my twitter developer account.

However, I'm having trouble combining these two things; trying to post to twitter on ***behalf of another user***. For that, I need to get the user's access token and access token secret. Then, I need to make a post request to the Twitter API with that information.

I'm not sure where to put the post request in the passport-twitter code. I tried putting it in the second route which is the URL to which Twitter redirects the user after they have signed in.

```
   app.get('/twitter/login', passport.authenticate('twitter'))

   app.get('/twitter/return', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
       failureRedirect: '/'
   }), function(req, res) {
     //Post using twit
     //grab access token and access token secret from the request query
       const access_token = req.query.oauth_token;
       const access_token_secret = req.query.oauth_verifier;

       //set the configurations with the access token and access token secret that we just got
       const config = {
         consumer_key:         <consumer key here>,
         consumer_secret:      <consumer secret here>,
         access_token, 
         access_token_secret,
         timeout_ms:           60*1000,  
         strictSSL:            true
       }

       //pass in the configurations
       var T = new Twit(config);

       //post
       T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'hello world!' }, function(err, data, response) {
         if (err)console.log("oops, didn't tweet: ", err.message);
       })

       res.redirect('/');
   })
```

But I got an error: `Invalid or expired token.`

I expected it to work because the authentication worked.

This is my first time using OAuth so perhaps I misunderstand how this all works.

Where am I supposed to put the post request?

**UPDATE:**

I tried posting to my dev account, using my dev account's access token and secret. It worked. Which lead me to believe there is something wrong with the access token and secret for the user.

I think I know partially what’s going.

I assumed that the property `oauth_verifier` found in the request query object was the access token secret.

```
const access_token_secret = req.query.oauth_verifier;
```

But now I don’t think `oauth_verifier` is the same as the access token secret. `oauth_verifier` has less characters than my dev account’s access token secret. So it seems that the datatypes are different.

But now I’m trying to figure out where the access token secret is? There are only two properties in the request query object (`req.query`);

- `oauth_token`
- `oauth_verifier`

Where’s the access token secret for the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my issue. It was in the documentation for [passport-twitter](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter) all along. Man, I spent days on this issue.

> The strategy also requires a verify callback, which receives the **access token** and **corresponding secret** as arguments, as well as profile which contains the authenticated user's Twitter profile.

-*from [passport-twitter readMe](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter)*

In the example in the [docs](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter), you can see `token` and `tokenSecret` in the params.

```js
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
  consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ twitterId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

I read this and saw this before. But assumed this was the the **consumer key** and **consumer secret**. I didn't realize it was what I was looking for: the **access token** and **access secret**.

So your post to twit would go something like this:

```
passport.use(new Strategy({
  consumerKey: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumerSecret: process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET,
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/twitter/return'
}, function(token, tokenSecret, profile, callback) {
  const configs = createConfigs(token, tokenSecret);


  // Post to twitter

  var Twit = require('twit')

  var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         '...', //get this from developer.twitter.com where your app info is
    consumer_secret:      '...', //get this from developer.twitter.com where your app info is
    access_token:         token,
    access_token_secret:  tokenSecret,
    timeout_ms:           60*1000,  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
    strictSSL:            true,     // optional - requires SSL certificates to be valid.
  })

  //
  //  tweet 'hello world!'
  //
  T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'hello world!' }, function(err, 
  data, response) {
    console.log(data)
  })


  return callback(null, profile);
}));
```

Comment: Hi @MuhanadY I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking

Comment: thank you very much for your respond. I did resolve the issue and forgat to remove the comment. sorry for that