# Twitter API - Migrate working code (POST on behalf of another user) from Express to ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, twitter

So I'm using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58849249/post-to-twitter-on-behalf-of-another-user-using-node-js-express-twit-and-pass) as an example to test `POST/GET`. I've tested actions that I wanted to do which are `Follow and Retweet`. But now the problem is this code works on `Express` and my project is in ReactJS so how do I convert these code to let this work in `React`?
Here's my code:

```js
var Twit = require('twit');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var Strategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
var session = require('express-session');

passport.use(new Strategy({
    consumerKey: '...',
    consumerSecret: '...',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/twitter/return'
}, function(token, tokenSecret, profile, callback) {
    const configs = createConfigs(token, tokenSecret);


    // Post to twitter

    var Twit = require('twit')

    var T = new Twit({
      consumer_key:         '...', //get this from developer.twitter.com where your app info is
      consumer_secret:      '...', //get this from developer.twitter.com where your app info is
      access_token:         token,
      access_token_secret:  tokenSecret,
      timeout_ms:           60*1000,  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
      strictSSL:            true,     // optional - requires SSL certificates to be valid.
    })

    // tweet hello world
    T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'hello world!' }, function(err, 
    data, response) {
      console.log(data)
    })

  return callback(null, profile);
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, callback) {
    callback(null, user);
})

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, callback) {
    callback(null, obj);
})

const app = express();
const port_no = 5555 

//view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Server Setup
app.listen(port_no, () => {
    console.log('port running atport number : 5555')
})
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({secret: 'whatever', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())



app.get('/' , (req,res) => {
    res.render('testpage')
})
app.get('/twitter/login', passport.authenticate('twitter'))

app.get('/twitter/return', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failureRedirect: '/'
}), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/')
})

module.exports = app;
```

So the code above is mainly to login into user's twitter then make `POST` action according to the `API`. So I would need some help so that I can make this thing works in my React project.

Comment: So what does your React version of the code look like, and what is not working? Stack Overflow is not a code conversion service, what have you tried already?

Comment: @AndyPiper I have no idea how to start with. Does the code work on frontend or I can only `POST/GET` on backend?

Comment: Twitter does not support CORS so you cannot run it on the frontend.